# a list of squares of all the even numbers in a given range in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I need to return a list of squares of all the even numbers in a given range. So the function is "squares low high". An example input and output would be squares 1 6 = [4,16,36]. So far I have this, I think my logic is sound but as I am VERY new to Haskell, I am not sure what is wrong here,

```
    Squares low high = 
         let aux xxs low high
         | ([rem low 2] /= 0) = aux xxs (1 + low) high
         | ([rem low 2]==0) = aux ([low * low] ++ xxs) (1  + low) high
         | otherwise = xxs
         in aux [] low high
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove brackets around `rem low 2`. Also, you have three cases: equal 0, not equal 0, and... "otherwise"? What do you expect to fall in this last case? Maybe you need to check for `low < high`.

Comment: I would consider rewriting this as a list comprehension. You can read about list comprehensions here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out

Comment: I thought the otherwise case just returns the list when the first two cases don't work. Anyways I turned it into a (low == high) case And I removed the brackets from rem low 2, now it goes into an infinite loop

Comment: You already consider the remainder of dividing the numbers by 2. You could consider that rounding odd `low` up and odd `high` down can be done without branching on the remainder. It is straightforward to write a list comprehension then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Squares low high = -- ...
```

This line is already broken, since only types/modules may start with an uppercase letter.

```
 let aux xxs low high
 | ([rem low 2] /= 0) = aux xxs (1 + low) high
 | ([rem low 2]==0) = aux ([low * low] ++ xxs) (1  + low) high
 | otherwise = xxs
```

How long will `aux` get called? You only stop recursing when you hit `otherwise`. But a integral number is either even or odd, so you will never return `xss`. Instead, you want to check whether `low > high`.

Note that you can define `squares` without auxiliary function:

```
squares low high
  | low > high  = []
  | even low    = low*low : squares (low + 1) high
  | otherwise   = squares (low + 1) high
```

Or using `map` and `filter`:

```
squares low high = map (^2) . filter even $ [low..high]
```

Or list comprehension (which is basically syntactic sugar for `map` and `filter`):

```
squares low high = [x^2| x <- [low..high], even x]
```

Comment: no need to test every x that it's even. Just round low up and high down: `squares low high = [4*x*x | x <- [div (low+1) 2..div high 2]]`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do something like:

```
squares :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
squares low high = aux [] low high
    where aux xxs low high
        | low > high = xxs
        | rem low 2 /= 0 = aux xxs (1 + low) high
        | otherwise = aux (xxs ++ [low * low]) (1  + low) high
```

Your guards are wrong for a couple of reasons. Firstly, `[rem low 2]` is a `[Int]` not an `Int` so you need to remove the brackets. Secondly, your `otherwise` clause will never be reached since one of the first two cases must be true. You should move the terminating check to the beginning.

You are also building the output list in the wrong order - if you want the next value to go at the end you should use `xxs ++ [low * low]` when adding a new element. Note that building lists using `++` is inefficient and it is better to add elements to lists from the front using `(:)`.

Finally, you can do this in a much simpler way using `map` and `filter`:

```
squares low high = map (\x -> x * x) . filter even $ [low .. high]
```

or a list comprehension:

```
squares low high = [x * x | x <- [low .. high], even x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate numbers from `low` to `high`:

```
gen a b = a : gen (a+1) b
```

right?... no, wrong: it doesn't stop. Can we add the stopping condition?

```
gen a b | .....     = []
        | otherwise = a : gen (a+1) b
```

What if we want only even numbers?

```
gen a b | .....            = []
        | rem ... ... == 0 = a : gen (a+1) b
        | otherwise        =     .....
```

It's easy to tweak it to produce squares. But do we really need to test the numbers that we ourselves generate? What if `a` is even?

```
gen a b | even a = g a 
  where 
    g a | .....     = []
        | otherwise = a : g (a+2)    -- only evens are generated
```

And what if it is odd?..